# Why can I only pickle 2 files BUT only unpickle one?

Tags: python

So this does the pickling and unpickling:

```
def _read_all_from_file(self):
    self._items_dictionary = {}
    list_of_lines = []
    if os.path.getsize(self.__filename) > 0:
        with open(self.__filename, 'rb') as file:
            lines = pickle.load(file)
            #print(type(lines))
            lines = lines.split(',')
            list_of_lines.append(lines)
            for item in list_of_lines:
                if item != "":
                    entity = self.__read_entity(item)
                    self._items_dictionary[entity.id] = entity


def _write_all_to_file(self):
    with open(self.__filename, 'wb') as file:
        for entity in self._items_dictionary.values():
            line = self.__write_entity(entity)
            print(line)
            pickle.dump(line,file)
```

And the thing is that I can only pickle two files but when it comes to unpickling I only get one back, and as soon as I try to add another one, the second one from  the pickle file gets updated to this third one.

Comment: See my update for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are dumping multiple lines to the same file. When you try to load the data back, you need to repeatedly call `pickle.load` on the same file object until it raises `EOFError`.

```
 with open(self.__filename, 'rb') as file:
      while True:
          try:
            lines = pickle.load(file)
          except EOFError:
            # If we reach here it means we've already load all data from the file
              break
          # do something with the lines here
```

Note that unless the items you are trying to `dump` is really large, you may want to create a list of them and then just `dump` the list, it would be much simpler.